# Magento : Admin Magento Connect Manager is Showing Wrong Version

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, upgrade, magento-connect-manager

I have upgraded my site from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.3.2.

Now when I check in admin magento connect manager it show's version 1.8.1.0, 
and when I click to check for upgrade it show's 1.9.3.2 version to upgrade.

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the correct solution, may be someone who knows better can provide more details but for now this will resolve your issue.

Magento Connect Manager gets current version information for extensions from files added in `var/package` folder. If you open the folder, you will see all your installed packages xml files with its current version.

Most probably this you will still get files like **Package_Module-1.8.1.0.xml**
These files should get updated when you upgrade your Magento version but somehow they are not updated as per latest package version.

You can download latest Magento 1.9.3.2 version and copy all files from `var/package` folder and move to your setup's `var/package` folder. Make sure you remove Magento's old files with version 1.8.1.0

Comment: i do this but the error same .

Comment: Did you remove old files from `var/package`? Also make sure your cache is refreshed or disabled. And then move all package files from Magento 1.9.3.2 to your folder. It should work.

Comment: i do same as you say  but it not work

Comment: Do you get updated Magento version on your admin panel footer section?

Comment: in footer it shows 1.9.3.2

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your current `var/package` folder to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59345/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-jaimin-sutariya).